# What is the proper way to install the 3.4 kernel?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, kernel, shutdown, plymouth

Kernel 3.2 has an annoying error for my wireless card (rtl8192se-b) that makes the connection drop and/or prevents the card to make a connection to the wireless router. Dealing with it was very frustrating until I found out the bug was corrected in 3.4.
I downloaded:

- `linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb`
- `linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb`
- `linux-image-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_amd64.deb`

and installed with: `sudo dpkg -i *`

Now the wireless works fine, but I have two problems that cannot solve.
The first one is minor: plymouth would not start at all. But if I boot with the 3.2 kernel it works fine.

The second one is serious: sometimes the computer won't shut down or reboot. The X server terminates but the computer shows part of my grub background and will stay there forever using 100% of the CPU.

I have a Toshiba Qosmio with an Core i7 and nvidia graphic card (using nvidia-current).
During one shutdown, I briefly read a message that said that the virtualbox module couldn't be unloaded from the kernel. I tried to solve this by removing and purging virtualbox and installing it back. I don't see the message anymore, but sometimes the computer won't shutdown nor reboot.

Am I missing something to properly configure the new kernels?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140254/how-to-install-linux-3-4

Answer (score 1):

How to install Linux Kernel 3.5 in Ubuntu 12.04. WARNING This isn't worth doing unless you're having problems with the old kernel or you're adding new hardware which is unsupported in old Kernel 3.2, such as nVidia Kepler (600 series) or AMD HD 7000 series Graphics cards.

Improvements in Kernel 3.4:

- Reduced Power Usage
- Speed improvements for BTRFS file systems
- More wireless network drivers from Ralink and Broadcom added
- Support for nVidia Kepler chipsets (600 series)
- Support for AMD Southern Islands GPUs (HD 7000 series)
- Support for AMD Trinity Processors

Ubuntu Kernel Website: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Look for the latest Kernel:

Download linux-headers-3.4.x-xxx-all.deb, plus the headers and image for your system architecture.

e.g. linux-headers-3.4.x-xxx-i386.deb, and linux-image-3.4.x-xxx-generic-i386.deb for 32bit systems.

```
Open Terminal
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot

Check the new kernel is running with either System Monitor or "uname -r"

If you have any problems with the new kernel reboot and select "Previous Versions" on the Grub Menu (hold down Shift key if Grub doesn't show by default)

Remove auto updating old Kernel:

In Synaptic remove: linux-generic, linux-headers-generic, linux-image-generic
You can also remove any older kernels to free up some harddrive space.

I found this info [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=traegZveTKo&feature=player_detailpage)

Hope it helps, but read this too [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147651/nvidia-drivers-dont-work-with-mainline-kernel)